# Get values of Raster image based on shapefile mask

Tags: python, geospatial

I have a raster file, which consists of three individual 2D-numpy arrays (data, lat, lon), imported from a NetCDF file, and a shapefile (.shp). I want to use the shapefile as mask to calculate mean, median, and standard deviation of all data points within the mask. What would be the best of doing this in Python?

[This is how it looks like on the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiIEM.jpg)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas
plume = geopandas.read_file(shapefile)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree)
f = ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, np.ma.masked_invalid(data), shading='auto', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plume.boundary.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the rasterio library. Geopandas' (Vectordata) counterpart for handling rasterdata. Handles masking as well as calculations on the data.